# Possible bug regarding the displayed user

Tags: support, questions

I'm on the page [math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/algorithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/algorithms) and looking at the question [Squaring a matrix using a linear memory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255763/squaring-a-matrix-using-a-linear-memory). On the homepage the question appears to be asked by user [Omnomnomnom](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/81360/omnomnomnom)
but the question was actually asked by user [user931392](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/90838/user931392).

The question appears in [user931392](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/90838/user931392)'s history and not in [Omnomnomnom](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/81360/omnomnomnom)'s. The only bug seems to be [Omnomnomnom](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/81360/omnomnomnom)'s name appearing on the page containing the list of questions. Neither doing a hard refresh (Ctrl+Shift+r) or navigating away from and back to the page seem to fix this.

Here are screenshots of what I am seeing in case this is happening just for me:

[image: homepage-screenshot]

[image: question-screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your screenshot says

> modified 3 hours ago
>
> Omnomnomnom

This can refer to several kinds of activity on the question, including bounties, edits, answers, and edits to those answers. (And being the last to reopen; pointed out by quid.)

In this case, Omnomnomnom posted an answer and then deleted it. You don't see the answer, but the reason why the question was bumped had  to be stated anyway.

The revision history of the question, accessible either via "edited" link or (if the link isn't present) via `math.stackexchange.com/posts/{post-id}/revisions`, will list the edit and reopening events on the question. If you don't find a reason there, nor is there any visible answer activity, it has to be a deleted answer.

For the reasons why the system works this way, see:

- [Unbump a question if the answer providing the bump is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120326/unbump-a-question-if-the-answer-providing-the-bump-is-deleted)
- [Does deleting an answer bump its question at the top of the homepage?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81498/does-deleting-an-answer-bump-its-question-at-the-top-of-the-homepage)

Comment: Alright. I would have presumed that "Modified $n$ hours ago by ..." would only mean that the question itself was edited. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like if the answer was deleted, though, then it shouldn't be the thing that displays as the latest modification to the question. The latest activity should be the last event that *actually modified* the question.

Comment: I take my last comment back. If a question is answered for a long time but then the user who answered the question suddenly (for whatever reason) deletes their answer, then that should bump the modification time on the post.

Comment: You may want to read the discussions in the links I just added.